# Print Tkinter Entry box value to a label

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-entry

I am looking to simply print the value from a Tkinter Entry box into a label.

```
myLabel = ttk.Label(tab1, text="Enter your selection: ")
myLabel.grid(column=0, row=3)
labelEntry = tk.Entry(tab1)
labelEntry.grid(column=1, row=3, padx=10, pady=10)
```

Unfortunately I can't get my head around printing the value to a label. Is it possible to make it "live"? So as you are typing into the Entry text box the label populates too?

Also, how can I make the label be capitalised?

Is there an easy way to make this into a function instead of using lambda?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use same tkinter `StringVar` on both the `Entry` and `Label` widgets:

```py
var1 = tk.StringVar()

labelEntry = tk.Entry(tab1, textvariable=var1)
labelEntry.grid(column=1, row=3, padx=10, pady=10)

outputLabel = ttk.Label(tab1, textvariable=var1)
outputLabel.grid(column=0, row=4, columnspan=2, padx=10, pady=10)
```

---

Updated: if you want the content of the label be capitalized, then you can bind a trace callback on the tkinter `StringVar` instead and update the text of the label with capitalized content of the variable:

```py
var1 = tk.StringVar()
labelEntry = tk.Entry(tab1, textvariable=var1)
labelEntry.grid(column=1, row=3, padx=10, pady=10)

outputLabel = ttk.Label(tab1)
outputLabel.grid(column=0, row=4, columnspan=2, padx=10, pady=10)

var1.trace_add('write', lambda *args:outputLabel.config(text=var1.get().upper()))
```

Comment: Is there a way to easily convert this into a function?